# How to implement a smart gwt Window that has two text item fields and a button item without using a Dynamic form or any other form component

Tags: window, smartgwt, dynamicform

I am using smart gwt version 2.4.

I have to implement a Window(smart GWT) that should contain two TextItem(Smart GWT) fields and a ButtonItem. Is there a way I can add these items to the window **without** having to use a Dynamic form or any form component for that matter? Having to add these components without using a form seems impossible. Is there a possible workaround for this. It becomes a huge workaround for me if I have to use a form. Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormItem are component used to compose a form. You cannot add them  directly as members of a layout. Why are you saying "it becomes a huge workaroud for me ....".
You declare a DynamicForm objetc add to it your TextItem and ButtonItem and add your form to your layout that's it.

Comment: "You declare a DynamicForm object add to it your TextItem and ButtonItem and add your form to your layout that's it."That is precisely what I do not want to do. I think there is no widget in smart gwt for text apart from the TextItem according to [https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/features/gwt/smartgwt] which can only be used within a form. Why I say it is a workaround for me is because of UI Issues when I use a DynamicForm.

Comment: The problem was that I was using GWT and Smart GWT Widgets together, which was not wise. So I had to revert back to using only GWT Widgets.